# send post method with jquery

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest, activexobject

I've got this code, and i don't see where the problem is :

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    alert("bon");
    xhr =getXMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", "handlingData.php",true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("type="+$('input[name="type'+id+'"]').val()+"&titre="+$('input[name="titre'+id+'"]').val()+"&texte="+$('input[name="texte'+id+'"]').val()+"&reponse="+$('input[name="reponse'+id+'"]').val());

}
```

what i wanted to do was to send data in a POST.

Here's getXMLHttpRequest() :

```
function getXMLHttpRequest() {
var xhr = null;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest || window.ActiveXObject) {
    if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch(e) {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    } else {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    }
} else {
    alert("Votre navigateur ne supporte pas l'objet XMLHTTPRequest...");
    return null;
}

return xhr;
}
```

Comment: why not do the `post` with jQuery?

Comment: i'm sorry to tell you this but this wasn't me who did this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use jQuery you could use [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

```
// i'll show just to for example
var data = { 
    type : $('input[name="type'+id+'"]').val(),
    titre : $('input[name="titre'+id+'"]').val()
}
$.post('handlingData.php', data, function(response) {
    // do something after the server responded
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xhr.send() line looks like a GET request.  When using POST, send form data.  Since you're using jQuery, see the documentation:  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use the jQuery post method?  You're already using jQuery, might as well!

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
var data = { type: $('input[name="type'+id+'"]').val() }; // Fill this in with the data from your form.

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'handlingData.php',
  data: data,
  success: function(data) {
      // Do processing here...
  }
});
```